# Load manifest assemblies dynamically into appdomain

Tags: c#, .net, windows, visual-studio

I have 2 projects:

```
Main (Console)
Util (Class library)
```

I want the best of both worlds and I'm unsure if this is possible.

Say I have this class in my `Util` library:

```
public static class Helper
{
    public static int AnswerToUniverse()
    {
        return 42;
    }
}
```

I add the class library `Util` as a dependency to `Main` through Visual Studio `Project -> Add Reference`. This puts it in the manifest of `Main` and allows me to use all the types exposed in the `Util` library statically, with all the Intellisense goodness.

I always thought that the runtime loads these statically linked assemblies right on startup but it seems if I remove all uses from `Util` in my `Main` project but keep it as a reference and then remove the `.dll` assembly file from the working directory of `Main` that it still runs fine so I concluded that it gets loaded upon first use.

Now, I won't have the assembly file `Util` in my working directory but I do have the raw bytes of it so I'd like to dynamically load the content of the `Util` assembly as raw bytes into the app domain at runtime before the first use of any of its methods.

I could remove the static dependency and then use reflection, something like:

```
var assembly = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Load(rawBytes);
assembly.GetType("Util.Helper").GetMethod("AnswerToUniverse") // etc.. etc..
```

But I'd very much still like to be able to just do:

```
var answer = Helper.AnswerToUniverse();
```

I've already tried to hook `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve` but that doesn't seem to get called on statically referenced assemblies.

Test code:

Util, Helper.cs:

```
namespace Util
{
    public static class Helper
    {

        public static int AnswerToUniverse()
        {
            return 42;
        }
    }
}
```

Main, Program.cs:

```
using Util;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Main
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve;
            Console.WriteLine(Helper.AnswerToUniverse());
        }

        private static System.Reflection.Assembly CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
        {
            File.WriteAllText("test.txt", "assemblyresolved");
            Console.WriteLine("resolved.");
            Console.Out.Flush();
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Every time I run my `Main` without the `Util` assembly file in the working directory I get a `FileNotFoundException`, is this somehow interceptable so I can return the assembly loaded from the raw bytes or am I stuck using reflection as shown above?

Comment: @HansPassant It's for a CTF challenge the team is creating. I'm aware this is not best practices. `Main` is supposed to dynamically load `Util` from a byte array which in turn comes from previous steps of the CTF. If I can't load it without removing the static reference and thus have to use `GetMethod` etc then so be it but I was wondering if there was a way to keep the static type checking and also load from bytes.

Comment: @HansPassant Yes, David's answer seems to do what you described, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'd like to dynamically load the content of the Util assembly as raw bytes into the app domain

> I've already tried to hook AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve

That's the correct approach.  The AssemblyResolve will be invoked when the JITter needs to compile any type in the target assembly.

And since JIT triggers this, you have to hook AssemblyResolve before the JITter tries to compile any references to the target assembly.  So this

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve;
    Console.WriteLine(Helper.AnswerToUniverse());
}
```

Won't work, as the compilation of Main will trigger the loading of the Helper assembly, but you haven't hooked AssemblyResolve yet.

And because

> The loader creates and attaches a stub to each method in a type when
> the type is loaded and initialized. When a method is called for the
> first time, the stub passes control to the JIT compiler, which
> converts the MSIL for that method into native code and modifies the
> stub to point directly to the generated native code. Therefore,
> subsequent calls to the JIT-compiled method go directly to the native
> code.

[Compilation by the JIT Compiler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/managed-execution-process#compilation-by-the-jit-compiler)

It's enough to push the first use of Helper into a seperate method (and prevent that method from being "inlined" into Main), so Main can be compiled start executing before the first time Helper is needed.  Eg

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve;
    Run();
}

[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)]
static void Run()
{
   Console.WriteLine(Helper.AnswerToUniverse());
}
```

Comment: Exactly, but somehow my callback isn't being called if I add the assembly through `Project -> Add Reference` and then remove the physical file so it's unable to be loaded.

Comment: Done! edited my post. In this test case the console logs anything nor the file is created.

Comment: See updated answer.  You need to hook AssemblyResolve _before_ the JITter needs the Helper assembly.

Comment: That works! Amazing, thank you. I thought using it before at any time was sufficient, I didn't know it was per-method in this case.